# Issue in Exporting CSV file from a custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, export

I have a custom module in admin panel,when I click  at "Export" button following function is called. CSV is being exported and downloaded correctly, in CSV one column is having id's instead of value of field.So I just want to changes to the value for that column, But I can't find where data is being dumped into csv file.

```
class Abc_AddressManager_Adminhtml_StoresController extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
 public function exportCsvAction() {
    $fileName = 'stores.csv';
    $content = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('abc_addressmanager/adminhtml_stores_csv')
            ->getCsvFile();

    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
 }
}
```

And

```
class Abc_AddressManager_Block_Adminhtml_Stores_Csv extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $customer_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $select = $collection->getSelect();

    $select->joinLeft(
            array('customer' => $collection->getTable('customer/entity')), 'customer.entity_id=e.parent_id', array('email' => 'email')
    );

    $d = $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
protected function _prepareColumns() {

    $addressModel = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
    $addressForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
    $addressForm->setFormCode('adminhtml_customer_address')
            ->setEntity($addressModel)
            ->initDefaultValues();
    $attributes = $addressForm->getAttributes();

    $this->addColumn('email', array(
        'header' => 'email',
        'type' => 'text',
        'index' => 'email',
        'filter' => false,
        'sortable' => false,
    ));
$this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header' => 'address_id',
            'type' => 'text',
            'index' => 'entity_id',
            'filter' => false,
            'sortable' => false,
        ));
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {

        $code = $attribute->getData('attribute_code');

        $this->addColumn($code, array(
            'header' => $code,
            'type' => 'text',
            'index' => $code,
            'filter' => false,
            'sortable' => false,
        ));
    } // end 

    return $this;
}
```

My field Column is "Ownership", that is a customer attribute, type drop down,its attribute_id =554 in **eav_attribute** table, and option id's are =438 to 443 in **eav_attribute_option**, and values for option is stored in **eav_attribute_option_value**,in csv file, column name is **Ownership**, but its has option id's(438 to 443) in it, instead of their value. My grid look like this.As you can see, Ownership has value(CO), in csv it here I am getting '439' option_id for "CO"
[image: Admin grip]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `_prepareColumns` function inside your custom block

```
Class abc_Addressmanager_Block_Adminhtml_Stores_Csv extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid_Abstract {

     protected function _prepareCollection()
     { 
          //please make sure to set collection here and having all columns you want to load in the query
     }

     protected function _prepareColumns()
     {
        //for debuging
        $collection = $this->getCollection();
        //printing the query using this command (if $collection object is set)
        echo   $collection->getSelect();
        //making sure the fields you want to show up is in the query output
        //you can add or remove columns here
     }    

}
```

Comment: Can see my update

Comment: I am doing as you said

Comment: could you show up adminhtml grid?

Comment: you can see it, I can't show full grid, it is too large

Comment: I added some  tips for you above. Hope it helps

Comment: you can see my function **_prepareColumns()**, when I print the query, I got following **SELECT `e`.*, `customer`.`email` FROM `customer_address_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `customer_entity` AS `customer` ON customer.entity_id=e.parent_id WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '2')**

Comment: I don't find any way to get value of option

Comment: Do you see the option value when you run the query inside phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

The block is extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` which has this function `getCsvFile`
Now following the calls from there:

- `getCsvFile` is calling `_exportCsvItem`
- `_exportCsvItem` calls `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column::getRowFieldExport`
- Now `getRowFieldExport` calls `$this->getRenderer()->renderExport($row);`
- Wich is found in the abstract renderer `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract` and calls `$this->render($row);`

Now in your case it should be the "Select" Renderer which is `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Select` you can find the render function there, or it might be another Render, you can insert log code and test which one is it.

Comment: I have debugged my project, it always calls to **render()** from 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Longtext', not from 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Select'  as you said.